# Take numbers from an unsorted string and convert them to a list with each number separated by a comma

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

I have an input:

```
L1 = input()
```

I want the output to be:

```
[1, 7, -3, 10, 42, 5, 0, 17]
```

The input is "1 7 -3 10 42 5 0 17" which means that when I print L1, it yields:

```
1 7 -3 10 42 5 0 17
```

Using inp(input()) gives me "Invalid literal for int() with base 10:".
Using .split does not change the output.

If I get the user input as a list, then it yields:

```
[1 7 -3 10 42 5 0 17]
```

The string of numbers cannot be inputted individually, it must be inputted as a whole and then "split" with a comma. However;

```
L1 = input()
L1.split() or L1.split(",")
print(L1)
```

just yields...

```
1 7 -3 10 42 5 0 17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for L1 to be updated properly, you have to assign it the value that L1.split() returns.

```
L1 = "1 7 -3 10"
L1 = L1.split()
print(L1)
```

**Output:**
`['1', '7', '-3', '10']`

Or if you want a list of integers:

```
L1 = "1 7 -3 10"
L1 = [int(i) for i in L1.split()]
print(L1)
```

**Output:**
`[1, 7, -3, 10]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's what I needed.

Comment: No problem, if it worked out the way you planned feel free to mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split by space or comma, you should use regexp splitting. Also, the split items are type `str` and you probably want to convert them to type `int`.

Here's the code:

```
import re
L1 = input()
L1 = [int(i) for i in re.split('[\s,]+', L1) if i]
print(L1)
```